# django 1.3 upgrade problem

Tags: django, mod-python

I recently updgraded to django 1.3. After the upgrade, I get the following error whenever I used `request.POST`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 86, in  get_response
response = None

File "/public/gdp/trunk/src/ukl/lis/process/utils/error_handler.py", line 15, in __call__
return self.function(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 30, in _cache_controlled
# and this:

File "/public/gdp/trunk/src/ukl/lis/process/authentication/views.py", line 438, in login
form = loginForm(request.POST)

File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 101, in _get_post
self._load_post_and_files()

AttributeError: 'ModPythonRequest' object has no attribute '_load_post_and_files'
```

Once I reverted back to django 1.0 the error is fixed.

Why is django 1.3 alone throwing this error? How to correct it?

Comment: chackout your middleware_classes in the settings

Comment: can you explain what exactly should i check in middleware_classes?

Comment: btw. if you're within the upgrade process, you should consider switching from mod_python to wsgi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried re-installing my mod-python and now the error is fixed. Now thinking of migrating to mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 1):

Stepping from Django 1.0 to Django 1.3 is a big jump, a lot of items might have been deprecated or no longer used, I recommend you to just check some of the documentation for the middleware_classes

[Django Middleware documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs)